# Moodle Installation php problems

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, apache2, moodle

I want to solve a problem in moodle 3.11.8 :

> Fatal error: Type of xml_format_exception::$line must be int (as in class Exception) in /var/www/moodle/lib/xmlize.php on line 0

I use PHP ***8.1.24***,

> apache2 on linux mint

Comment: You are using a moodle version (from 2022) that is no longer supported with a php version (from 2023). I would suggest updating to a newer version of moodle that supports your php version and might even have already fixed that issue. [https://moodledev.io/general/development/policies/php](https://moodledev.io/general/development/policies/php)

Comment: @ouya olivier if your moodle is 3.11.8 you need to use the php 8.0 check docs about [php supported versions](https://moodledev.io/general/development/policies/php#php-80)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Moodle 3.11 isn't compatible with PHP 8.1

And support for PHP 8.1 is still in development for Moodle 4.x

You'll need to use PHP 8.0

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_and_PHP