# (Windows) PHP has not been properly configured with the PGSQL extension so that it can communicate with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, windows, moodle

I am installing Moodle on a Windows server using PostgreSQL 12 and PHP version 8.2.12

During the install process, I get the following:

> Error: database driver problem detected
>
> The site administrator should verify server configuration
>
> PHP has not been properly configured with the PGSQL extension so that
> it can communicate with PostgreSQL. Please check your php.ini file or
> recompile PHP.

I uncommented the following extensions:

> extension=pdo_mysql
>
> extension=pdo_pgsql
>
> extension=pgsql

and added the following 2:

> extension=php_pgsql.dll
>
> extension=libpq.dll

I restarted the web server, but still no luck - please could you assist

Comment: Does it show as enabled in`phpinfo()`? Did you edit the correct `php.ini` file mentioned in `phpinfo()`?

Comment: correct php.ini file edited - not sure where in phpinfo it will show, because I cannot find anything

Comment: Also what's your versions of : Moodle, psql and php ?

Comment: PostgreSQL 12 and PHP version 8.2.12 and Moodle 4.3+

Comment: Ok so moodle 4.3 needs : PHP 8.0 (i had problems with php 8.2) but also postgresql 13 minimum https://moodledev.io/general/releases/4.3#server-requirements

Comment: Thank you @Veterini worked like a charm after the downgrade to php 8.0 and postgre 13

Comment: Nice, good to read ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to follow up the exchange in the comments, the answer was the versions of PHP and PostgreSQL.
As the documentation states, Moodle 4.3 has the following requirements :
https://moodledev.io/general/releases/4.3#server-requirements

- PHP 8.0.x (It's to be noted that php 8.2 & 8.3 may generate unforseen problems. It's best to wait for future release before upgrading to these versions)
- PostgreSQL 13

Comment: For reference, Moodle currently only supports PHP 8.0, support for PHP 8.1 is still in development https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77375246/moodle-installation-php-problems/77376781#77376781

Comment: yeah i had an issue when deploying 4.1 and it's this specific post of yours that told me i was being overly motivated on the php upgrade :D